# In PowerBI - Find the percentages of customers who have purchased again in 90 day duration and same cust bought prod in following 3 months

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am new to Power BI. how can i solve this problem?

I have two tables  1st Customertable has 'CustomerKey' and 'DateOffirstPurchase' Columns 2nd Salestable has Customer Key and OrderDate columns.

I want to find the  customers who have purchased again within in 90 day duration from first Purchase and if the same customer bought in following 3 months duration excluding the month of the first Purchase [For example If Jimmy’s first purchase was in July, I want to know whether he bought again in Aug, Sept, or Oct].

Customer Table:

[image]

Customer table sample data:

```
CustomerKey DateFirstPurchase
11602   1/11/2004 0:00
12517   4/21/2004 0:00
12518   2/2/2004 0:00
12714   1/20/2004 0:00
12871   5/12/2004 0:00
13830   6/13/2004 0:00
13838   3/14/2004 0:00
14839   12/3/2003 0:00
14840   8/25/2003 0:00
14848   11/12/2002 0:00
16453   10/12/2003 0:00
16458   9/28/2003 0:00
16460   12/17/2003 0:00
18038   2/11/2002 0:00
19371   5/3/2004 0:00
19377   7/23/2004 0:00
19380   3/1/2003 0:00
19381   3/24/2003 0:00
19386   3/11/2003 0:00
19509   5/5/2004 0:00
19517   6/17/2003 0:00
19518   6/18/2002 0:00
20955   6/5/2004 0:00
21126   10/24/2003 0:00
22532   6/5/2004 0:00
```

Sales table:

[image]

Sales table sample data:

```
 CustomerKey    OrderDate
16688   7/2/2003 0:00
18212   7/7/2003 0:00
16702   7/9/2003 0:00
18246   7/10/2003 0:00
18243   7/11/2003 0:00
18214   7/15/2003 0:00
18222   7/23/2003 0:00
18210   7/24/2003 0:00
18250   8/3/2003 0:00
18470   8/3/2003 0:00
18308   8/7/2003 0:00
18482   8/8/2003 0:00
18307   8/11/2003 0:00
18252   8/12/2003 0:00
16713   8/12/2003 0:00
18483   8/17/2003 0:00
18273   8/23/2003 0:00
18248   8/29/2003 0:00
18485   8/30/2003 0:00
18489   9/3/2003 0:00
16744   9/9/2003 0:00
18710   9/18/2003 0:00
18487   9/20/2003 0:00
18736   9/22/2003 0:00
19559   10/8/2003 0:00
19084   10/8/2003 0:00
19095   10/11/2003 0:00
```

Final output:

[image]

I am able to achieve starting first two columns output using below query, But I want to know how to perform 3rd and 4th column output as shown above output image
To get 1 and 2nd column output I have used below measure in customer table:

```
Customers = COUNTROWS (
    EXCEPT (
        VALUES ( 'Customers'[CustomerKey] ),
        SUMMARIZE (
            FILTER (
                ALL ( 'Customers' ),
                'Customers'[DateFirstPurchase] < MAX ( 'Customers'[DateFirstPurchase].[Year] )
            ),
            'Customers'[CustomerKey]
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: This can be solved easily in Power Query with an Inner Join and then grouping. But your data doesn't provide any results since there are no customers that are in both tables.  It is always recommended to provide sample data that can be used to replicate your problem.

Comment: By the way, is this homework?  I ask because an almost identical question was posted about 15 hours ago by an apparently different user. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70587776/find-the-percentages-of-customers-who-have-purchased-again-in-90-day-and-3-month)

Comment: Hi Ron, Thanks for the response. Actually the sales Tables have around 10K records and many customers are repeated and have same Customer key. Since I can't give full data I took a only first few data.  Can you please share me the query that you used and got no results so that it will be helpful for me. I have already got the first two columns as mentioned in my query.

Comment: Won't do any good as I just checked to see if the data might produce anything other than a null table. When an InnerJoin produced a null table, I saw no point in going further.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this question and this is the approach I used in solving the question.
Question 1 - Customers who purchased items within the 90days after their first purchase.

```
Purchase within 90days(%) = 
VAR Customerlist = VALUES( Sales[CustomerKey] )
VAR Returndate = 90
VAR CountCustomers =  
COUNTROWS( 
    FILTER(
        Customerlist, 
        CALCULATE( COUNTROWS (Sales), 
            FILTER( ALLSELECTED ( 'Calendar' ),
            'Calendar'[Date] > ( MIN ( Sales[OrderDate] ) ) &&
             'Calendar'[Date] <  MIN ( Sales[OrderDate]) + Returndate 
             )
        ) >0
    )
)
Return
DIVIDE(CountCustomers,[Customers])
```

Question 2 - Customers who purchased items after the first 90days but not within the same month of their first purchase.

```
Purchasewithin3months = 
VAR Customerlist = VALUES( Sales[CustomerKey] )
VAR Returndate = 90
VAR CountCustomers =  
COUNTROWS( 
    FILTER(
        Customerlist, 
        CALCULATE( 
                COUNTROWS (Sales), 
                FILTER( 
                    ALLSELECTED ( 'Calendar' ),
                    'Calendar'[Date] >=  MIN ( Sales[OrderDate] )  &&
                    'Calendar'[Date] <=  MIN ( Sales[OrderDate]) + 90 &&
                     FORMAT('Calendar'[Date], "YYYYMM") <> FORMAT(MIN(Sales[OrderDate]), "YYYYMM")
            )
    ) > 0
)
)
RETURN 
CountCustomers
```